# Passing data from view controller to table view controller in ios swift 2

Tags: ios, swift

[image]I am using swift 2 beaucse my lappy does not suppoeted swift 3 beacuse of some issue.
I want to pass data from view controller to table view controller ..
but i got some error and here is my code

I want to pass value form view controller .I am using label . whatever i will write in label it will disply in table view controller. so it will REALTIME value !

I am using two view controller and one table view controller ...i have error in table view controller.
I have some errors

1) cell1.textLabel!.text = tblLable.text!  // error UItableview has no memeber in 'text'

> view controller

```
@IBOutlet var labelText: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
{
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
let DestViewController:PassDataView = segue.destinationViewController as! PassDataView
DestViewController.passdata = labelText.text!
 //print(DestViewController.passdata)
}
```

> passdataview

@IBOutlet var Label: UILabel!

```
var passdata=String()

override func viewDidLoad()
{
    Label.text=passdata
}
```

}

> tableviewcontroller

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    //myTableView.delegate = self;
   // myTableView.dataSource = self;
}

@IBOutlet var tblLable: UITableView!

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?)
{
    let DestViewController:PassDataView = segue.destinationViewController as! PassDataView
    DestViewController.passdata = tblLable.text!// error UItableview has no memeber in 'text' 
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell1.textLabel!.text = tblLable.text!  // error UItableview has no memeber in 'text' 
    return cell1
}
```

Comment: are there  two different view controller ?

Comment: A `UITableView` has no variable `text`, that's why you're seeing the error

Comment: then how i will disply my value?  cell1.textLabel!.text = tblLable.text!  @Ollie

Comment: Yes i am using two view controller @Dev_Tandel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare String variable in your 3rd View Controller (Table View Controller) like

```
var myString: String = ""

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}
```

You can assign value to myString variable from your first view controller like

```
let DestViewController:tableviewcontroller = segue.destinationViewController as! tableviewcontroller
DestViewController.myString = labelText.text!
```

And your your tableview view method will be like

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell1 = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell1", forIndexPath: indexPath)
    cell1.textLabel!.text = myString
    return cell1
}
```

The Above is the solution, below i am explaining what was the problem

There is no such text method for UITableview, hence you were getting error at

```
DestViewController.passdata = tblLable.text! //In first View Controller
cell1.textLabel!.text = tblLable.text! //In second View controller
```

Comment: Hope this helps in future too

Comment: DestViewController.myString = labelText.text!        //error no such text method for UITableview,

Comment: and i already declare value in passdataview controller
 see ---- var passdata=String()

Comment: You need to declare the string variable where you want to use it.

Comment: Change it to var passdata : String = "". () parentheses indicate this is class, we just need variable to of type String

Comment: Not work using clean project still getting error in has no member text in UITableview

Comment: will you please update code? So i can have look at ?

Comment: You need String variable at tableviewcontroller

Comment: I wrote answer as you told you have two view controller